# How do I setup Multiple monitors in games?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I was wondering how I would be able to play a video game such as Half life 2 or Crysis on a multi monitor setup. I have three Identical monitors running off of my PC, and would like to utilize it for games. I'm running Windows 7, so the "Horizontal Span" solution won't work. The cards are running off of the latest Nvidia driver.

Comment: Would help to know exactly what video card you have. Get GPU-Z if you don't know. And, what drivers and version you have.

Comment: I'm running on a GTX 460 and an 8200 from Nvidia.

Answer (score 2):

On almost all multi-monitor setups, you can game in one monitor while having your desktop extended over two or more. I'm assuming you want your game to stretch across multiple monitors, correct?

If so, the GTX 460 can do what Nvidia calls "3D Vision Surround". (Although there's the "3D" in it, it's just marketese for better multi-monitor support.) More info can be had [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/nvidia.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=2667). Make sure you have the most up-to-date drivers from NVidia's site.

And, [this site](http://www.widescreengamingforum.com/wiki/index.php/Category:Surround) has lots of info on individual titles. Not all games will play nice with wonky (a.k.a dual or triple wide) resolutions.